# Error loading and running event receiver - Event 6875

Tags: error

In my logs when some users try to add a document I get the following error:

```
Error loading and running event receiver Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSetItemsEventReceiver in Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Additional information is below.

: <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

A quick google for the error returns http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc560963(office.12).aspx which suggests repairing SharePoint 2010.

I have done this but am still getting the error. What are my next steps? 
**Update**

I am also getting:

```
Error loading and running event receiver Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PublishingWebEventReceiver in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Additional information is below.

: <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.
```

This is the same error 6875. The ULS gives me the following.

```
05/20/2011 15:39:19.93  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x0980  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/TestSite    bd88f237-0d33-4553-a631-fbca5ff50c97
05/20/2011 15:39:21.03  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x0980  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:https://mysrv:443/sites/TestSite/_layouts/inplview.aspx?Cmd=Ctx&List=%7BC3C299B4-8020-45A7-A70D-BFBCABC4B9D5%7D&View=%7BB35CE978-0990-4F43-82D3-45BC7B2DDC25%7D&ViewCount=141&IsXslView=TRUE&Field=LinkFilename&ID=11954&RootFolder=%5Csites%5CCaseDocs%5CDocuments%5CElfLive%5C11050085&ListViewPageUrl=https://mysrv/sites/TestSite/Documents/Forms/SimpleView.aspx)). Execution Time=1111.81068404731  bd88f237-0d33-4553-a631-fbca5ff50c97
05/20/2011 15:39:23.04  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x0C7C  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://mysrv:32843/bcfa7ec3a4024c1db0b9cc4c19cd179f/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:605d30c5-0235-4769-aa4b-9fb6df6a6616'   
05/20/2011 15:39:23.13  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x10E4  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mb    Medium  WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://mysrv.mycomp.local:32843/bcfa7ec3a4024c1db0b9cc4c19cd179f/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:605d30c5-0235-4769-aa4b-9fb6df6a6616' 708fc147-0672-4aa7-a87f-530ab8dcd538
05/20/2011 15:39:23.13  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x10E4  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    708fc147-0672-4aa7-a87f-530ab8dcd538
05/20/2011 15:39:23.13  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x10E4  SharePoint Server   Taxonomy    fuc5    Medium  MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' starting. 708fc147-0672-4aa7-a87f-530ab8dcd538
05/20/2011 15:39:23.13  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x10E4  SharePoint Server   Taxonomy    fuc6    Medium  MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' completed.    708fc147-0672-4aa7-a87f-530ab8dcd538
05/20/2011 15:39:23.15  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x10E4  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=6.43514442640248    708fc147-0672-4aa7-a87f-530ab8dcd538
05/20/2011 15:39:23.31  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x0C7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfOperation:http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges). Execution Time=267.597568583629 
05/20/2011 15:39:24.04  w3wp.exe (0x0348)   0x10B4  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://mysrv:32843/bcfa7ec3a4024c1db0b9cc4c19cd179f/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:52cceedb-1bc7-4155-97f5-4e7f7d9e4c76'   
05/20/2011 15:39:24.10  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x0F44  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mb    Medium  WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://mysrv.mycomp.local:32843/bcfa7ec3a4024c1db0b9cc4c19cd179f/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:52cceedb-1bc7-4155-97f5-4e7f7d9e4c76' a699934f-32cc-4b46-99cf-542645274408
05/20/2011 15:39:24.10  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x0F44  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    a699934f-32cc-4b46-99cf-542645274408
05/20/2011 15:39:24.10  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x0F44  SharePoint Server   Taxonomy    fuc5    Medium  MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' starting. a699934f-32cc-4b46-99cf-542645274408
05/20/2011 15:39:24.10  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x0F44  SharePoint Server   Taxonomy    fuc6    Medium  MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' completed.    a699934f-32cc-4b46-99cf-542645274408
05/20/2011 15:39:24.10  w3wp.exe (0x0AD8)   0x0F44  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=4.65371536766496    a699934f-32cc-4b46-99cf-542645274408
05/20/2011 15:39:27.28  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x0980  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request (POST:https://mysrv:443/sites/TestSite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Cmd=Delete&List=%7BC3C299B4-8020-45A7-A70D-BFBCABC4B9D5%7D&ID=11954&))    
05/20/2011 15:39:27.28  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x0980  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:https://mysrv:443/sites/TestSite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Cmd=Delete&List=%7BC3C299B4-8020-45A7-A70D-BFBCABC4B9D5%7D&ID=11954&)  535ed26d-5b3b-4789-9a8b-2be69d7206b5
05/20/2011 15:39:27.29  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x066C  SharePoint Foundation   General af71    Medium  HTTP Request method: POST   535ed26d-5b3b-4789-9a8b-2be69d7206b5
05/20/2011 15:39:27.29  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x066C  SharePoint Foundation   General af75    Medium  Overridden HTTP request method: POST    535ed26d-5b3b-4789-9a8b-2be69d7206b5
05/20/2011 15:39:27.29  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x066C  SharePoint Foundation   General af74    Medium  HTTP request URL: /sites/TestSite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Cmd=Delete&List={C3C299B4-8020-45A7-A70D-BFBCABC4B9D5}&ID=11954& 535ed26d-5b3b-4789-9a8b-2be69d7206b5
05/20/2011 15:39:27.38  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x066C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=36.5514614985369  535ed26d-5b3b-4789-9a8b-2be69d7206b5
05/20/2011 15:39:27.40  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x066C  SharePoint Foundation   General 8kh7    High    <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.    535ed26d-5b3b-4789-9a8b-2be69d7206b5
05/20/2011 15:39:27.40  w3wp.exe (0x0908)   0x066C  SharePoint Foundation   General 6875    Critical    Error loading and running event receiver Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PublishingWebEventReceiver in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Additional information is below.  : <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.   535ed26d-5b3b-4789-9a8b-2be69d7206b5
```

Very confused.

Comment: It looks like someone is trying to delete a list item and get access denied. Can you confirm?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

0x80070002 usually means that the system cannot find a specific file.

Please update your question with more details of how they add documents and where. It looks like they are adding items into a document set. Can you drill further into the ULS logs and see more information about that specific correlation id.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same thing, it ended up being I was trying to "share" a managed metadata column that had an empty value, and that blew up the event receiver